# no JavaScript auto complete in PyDev Eclipse project

Tags: javascript, eclipse, autocomplete, pydev, jsdt

I have Eclipse with PyDev and JavaScript Development Tools (JSDT).
I'm using this environment to develop web applications.

Python, HTML, and CSS editors all work fine: highlighting and auto completion works.
JavaScript highlighting works too, **but JavaScript auto completion does not work**.

Switching to the JavaScript perspective doesn't help.

However, if I create a separate `JavaScript Project` (rather than adding JavaScript files into my PyDev project), JavaScript auto completion seems to work properly.

**Additional Details**

When I create a `JavaScript Project`, Eclipse adds certain `JavaScript Resources` to the project by default. For example, `ECMAScript Built-In Library` and `ECMA 3 Browser Support Library`. These are visible in the `Script Explorer` window, as well as under `Project Properties -> JavaScript -> Libraries`.

The problem is, I don't have a `Project Properties -> JavaScript` option when in a `PyDev Project`.

**Question:** What do I need to do (e.g. config wise) to get JavaScript auto completion in Eclipse, when NOT in a `JavaScript Project` (i.e. when in a `PyDev Project`)?
Is it possible to add a JavaScript perspective/(I'm not sure what call this exactly...) to a `PyDev Project` in Eclipse?

I'm very new (2 days) to JavaScript development, so preemptive apologies if the problem/solution is trivial!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a javascript project first and then make it a PyDev project (right click it > PyDev > Set as PyDev project).

Also, if you're starting out, you may want to check Aptana Studio 3: http://aptana.org/ (it's set of Eclipse plugins that has the whole toolchain for web development, with editors for javascript, html, css as well as PyDev preinstalled) -- note that you can check it by just downloading the standalone version and pointing to an existing workspace.

Comment: perfect, creating a javascript project then making it a PyDev project worked perfectly (I don't even have to use the JavaScript perspective to get the JS editing benefits). thanks

Answer (score 4):

To add JavaScript to an existing project convert it to a 'Faceted Project' type and then add the JavaScript facet; to do so go 'Project' > 'Properties'.

[image]

Comment: This is the best way to do it, works in Eclipse Mars.

Answer (score 0):

To add JavaScript to an existing PyDev project (Daniel Sokolowski's answer doesn't work for PyDev in Eclipse Neon. Facets are only available for J2EE projects -- See [eclipse's documentation on project facets](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fcfacets.html)):

1. Close out eclipse.
2. Browse to your project folder and open the .project file with a text editor.
3. Add the following to the `<natures>` tag next to the pydev natures: `<nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>`
4. Save and reopen your project.

I could then go into `Project > Properties > JavaScript > Include Path` and add libraries to use for auto-completion. Both auto-completion and the JavaScript Editor save actions worked from the PyDev perspective.

This was in Eclipse Neon.